# What is the order of the seals for the door to open in level 6 of the Endless Paths?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

At the end of Level 6 of the Endless Paths there is a door which needs a specific order of the seals or stones to open. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Left slot: Sapphire seal (eye symbol)
- Middle slot:  Bloodstone Seal (sword symbol)
- Right slot:  Peridot Seal (chisel symbol)

Comment: It would be a good addition to inform, that the order is based on pattern matching symbols on the seals, seen in their descriptions.